# DATE_TRUNC function working in postgres but not working in MYSQL and

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to leverage 'date_trunc' function in a query and it returns the below error

> FUNCTION database.date_trunc does not exist.

Please advice
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DATE_FORMAT(created_at ,'%Y-01-01')` to get first day of year:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at ,'%Y-01-01') AS `year`, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM sales_order
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at ,'%Y-01-01')
ORDER BY `year`;
```

[`DATE_TRUNC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is supported by PostgreSQL.

Comment: It worked. Thank you !!